# rectangle that allows to scroll in another rectangle in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

What I want to achieve is a pink rectangle in which I have text and the black contour is for scrolling horizontally  that mean when I move it by mouse right or left I can scroll on my pink rectangle. so it has the same height but another width. This my code but it doesn't work:

```
<div class="pink-rectangle" [ngStyle]="{ 'width.px': rectangleWidth }">
<div class="scrollable-rectangle">
  <div class="text-content">
   test test 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="black-rectangle" [ngStyle]="{ 'width.px': rectangleWidth - 20 }" (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)">
</div>
</div>
```

and this the CSS:

```
 .pink-rectangle {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}

.scrollable-rectangle {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.text-content {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.black-rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

and the ts file:

```
  rectangleWidth = 400;
  initialX = 0;

  onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.initialX = event.clientX;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp);
  }

  onMouseMove = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    const deltaX = event.clientX - this.initialX;
    this.rectangleWidth += deltaX;
    this.initialX = event.clientX;
  }

  onMouseUp = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp);
  }
```